# I still cannot fix my wifi

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom, madwifi

Wifi does not work at all.
I've tried this: http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/how-to-fix-broadcom-43xx/
And also upgrading my kernels. I've also tried removing the drivers and updating them. However, I keep running into errors. I have the BroadCom  BCM43227 802.11b/g/

When I checked what my laptop recognized: ifconfig;

It showed only eth0 which is my wired network, and "lo"
But it doesn't show the wlan which is the wifi network.
So, I don't know what is happening with my wifi.
None of the software detect it.

I'm a newbie, so detailed instructions would be awesome.

Ubuntu 12.04.3

--- FIXED ---
Refer to : [Broadcom STA driver fails to install missing wl on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS / Linux 3.8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337974/broadcom-sta-driver-fails-to-install-missing-wl-on-ubuntu-12-04-3-lts-linux-3)

The issue you are dealing with seems to mainly appear on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS with the backported kernel 3.8.0-xx installed.

Please take a look at this bug report. As you can see it's a known problem and many different workarounds exist.

What worked for me was installing the latest bcmwl-kernel-source from Raring. You can find this package here. Make sure to download the right one for your system, e.g. this one if you have an amd64 machine.

You can install the package via:

sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb

Of course you will have to change the path to the deb file in accordance to where you downloaded it to.

You might have to execute the following command afterwards to get your wireless up and running:

sudo modprobe wl

Comment: Could you paste the output of running `iwconfig`?

Comment: The fix depends on your Ubuntu version. Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: lsb_release -d