# Broadcom STA wireless driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

When trying to activate the wireless driver, I get it could not be activated. It says to check the logs. I am a complete noobie to ubuntu and am generally trying to learn more about computers as I go. Here is the log. Any help would be extremely appreciated. My ethernet connection works fine, if that makes any difference.

`tail -f /var/log/jockey.log`

```
2013-08-27 21:52:41,104 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-08-27 21:52:41,129 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-08-27 21:52:51,349 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-08-27 21:52:58,681 WARNING: modinfo for module wl failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module wl

2013-08-27 21:52:58,681 WARNING: /sys/module/wl/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind wl driver
2013-08-27 21:52:58,750 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-08-27 21:54:07,963 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-08-27 21:54:07,980 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-08-27 21:54:08,004 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-08-27 22:07:53,899 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-08-27 22:07:59,045 WARNING: modinfo for module wl failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module wl

2013-08-27 22:07:59,046 WARNING: /sys/module/wl/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind wl driver
2013-08-27 22:07:59,088 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-08-27 22:08:13,260 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-08-27 22:08:13,282 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-08-27 22:08:13,318 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
```

`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 12)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 12)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4330/4350/4550]
02:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series]
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

`sudo lshw -c`

```
Hardware Lister (lshw) - B.02.15
usage: lshw [-format] [-options ...]
       lshw -version

    -version        print program version (B.02.15)

format can be
    -html           output hardware tree as HTML
    -xml            output hardware tree as XML
    -short          output hardware paths
    -businfo        output bus information

options can be
    -class CLASS    only show a certain class of hardware
    -C CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
    -c CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
    -disable TEST   disable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -enable TEST    enable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -quiet          don't display status
    -sanitize       sanitize output (remove sensitive information like serial numbers, etc.)
    -numeric        output numeric IDs (for PCI, USB, etc.)
```

`rfkill list all`

Doesnt return anything. Perhaps something here is the issue? It isn't picking up and available connections. I have a hard block button which I don't believe to be the problem on my laptop and have checked in boot settings to make sure wireless connections are enabled.

`lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Comment: Please **Edit** your question and include result of `lspci`, `sudo lshw -c network` & `rfkill list all`. Also include result of `lsb_release -a`.. may be this is the issue? But don't try unless you are very sure [Broadcom STA driver fails to install missing wl on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS / Linux 3.8](http://askubuntu.com/q/337974)

Comment: run this command it your terminal.. It will scan your all drivers and try to fix it, also if any proprietary drivers used, you can do some changes like enable/disable:
$ sudo (jockey-gtk &)
Post your comment here after that.

Comment: @SauravKumar The log above is from `jockey`

Comment: Yes I know. I just wanted to know if he tried to use jockey or not as graphical tool.

Comment: You didn't enter this command correctly `sudo lshw -c network`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow like below,

First execute following commands to install the packages

`sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev libc6-dev linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Now open the additional driver and try to reactivate the driver. If success reboot and check. If it succeeded and  on reboot your hardware is still not functioning try `rfkill unblock all`.

If activation fails, execute below commands,

`sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source` - if it fails don't worry

next

`sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-lpphy-installer`

Reboot again and retry.

Answer extracted from -[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers/126798#126798) . You can explore if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am a new user of Ubuntu 13.10 and new to Linux anything. The below worked on my card [14e4:4312] in Dell M6300 except with

```
firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

replaced by

```
firmware-b43-installer
```

Apparently the -lpphy part has been superseded.