# Wireless card driver installation

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers

I have problem installing drivers for Asus wl-138g v2 card.
First, after installing Ubuntu 12.04, I did everything that I could find with jockey-text or its GUI version. In the GUI version I got some error, generally discussed here:

[Broadcom STA wireless driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338210/broadcom-sta-wireless-driver)

However, after executing apt-get install command which was a part of the answer there and installing also b43-fwcutter thingy I rebooted the PC and i had no longer the proprietary driver listed in the list though the wireless connection is still not available.

Then I wanted to install drivers from asus.com .

There was that readme file in which there was an instruction:

> 1. Extract the tar package.       tar -xzvf src-.tar.gz
> 2. Build the Driver   cd src/linuxsta/src/wl/linux    in the makefile make sure to set the variables      CROSS_COMPILE=, if the the gcc
>      is not already in the $PATH or if a different compiler needs to be
>      used, and     GCC-REV=  dictates the path of the prebuild
>      regulatory binaries, to use while building the driver.(values it takes
>      now are 3.4.2 or 4.0.2),      if the kernel version is 2.6.14.3 the
>      driver expects that iee80211_crypto.ko module be loaded, prior to
>      loading this driver.
>
>    make clean  make
> 3. Test the Driver by loading it  insmod wl.ko

So I changed the Makefile so that:

```
GCC-REV:=4.6.2   //is that correct?
export CROSS_COMPILE :=/usr/bin/
```

And modified `LINUXDIR` to `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic` as it seemed to not find the Linux directory by its own.
I got something like this:

```
   root@Bartek:home/bart/Downloads/src/linuxsta/src/wl/linux# make
Linux Directory is /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic
Linux Kernel Versions is 3.8.0-29-generic
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/ M=/home/bart/Downloads/src/linuxsta/src/wl/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/bart/Downloads/src/linuxsta/src/wl/linux/wlc_led.o
In file included from /home/bart/Downloads/src/linuxsta/src/wl/linux/wlc_led.c:17:0:
/home/bart/Downloads/src/linuxsta/src/wl/linux/../../include/typedefs.h:166:40: error: conflicting types for ‘bool’
include/linux/types.h:29:17: note: previous declaration of ‘bool’ was here
In file included from /home/bart/Downloads/src/linuxsta/src/wl/linux/../../include/linux_osl.h:21:0,
                 from /home/bart/Downloads/src/linuxsta/src/wl/linux/../../include/osl.h:24,
                 from /home/bart/Downloads/src/linuxsta/src/wl/linux/wlc_led.c:19:
/home/bart/Downloads/src/linuxsta/src/wl/linux/../../include/linuxver.h:19:26: fatal error: linux/config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/home/bart/Downloads/src/linuxsta/src/wl/linux/wlc_led.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/bart/Downloads/src/linuxsta/src/wl/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

I'm not sure what does it mean (problem with GCC? with drivers?). The PC is pretty old, year 2004, runs on AMD Sempron 3100+ with 2GB of RAM.

Comment: Are you quite certain the STA driver is correct for your device? May we see: lspci -nn -d 14e4:

Comment: `root@BARTEK:/home/bart/Downloads/src/linuxsta/src/wl/linux# lspci -nn -d 14e4:
00:06.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If it isn't installed, that's fine, just continue:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

After a reboot, your wireless should be working.

Comment: thank you.however, now it seems like something is wrong with rebooting. it hangs on the screen where it is written 'ubuntu' and 5 dots are changing its color from white to orange, but it doesn't seem to shut down completely in the end.

Comment: Did it shut down eventually? Can you force a shutdown? After a reboot, is all well, wireless and otherwise?

Comment: i had it being shutting down for like 40 minutes and i finally used the power button, after booting again the wireless finally worked and it seems like that now it is working well :) thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Very happy to help. If your computer has trouble shutting down in the future, please feel free to ask a new question.