# Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell Inspiron - Wireless stopped working

Tags: wireless

I recently re-installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Machine.

After re-installation, I had problems installing wireless driver under Additional Drivers.

I tried a lot of different things, ultimately removing bcmwl-kernel-source and installing firmware-b43-lpphy-installer and b43-fwcutter.

Initially, nothing happened, but then out of the blue, I checked the internet tab and could see my network. I was able to connect and use wireless all day yesterday, but now it isn't working again.

Under internet icon in upper right hand corner, computer says wireless is enabled, but wireless networks are disconnected.

Below I've included some info.

```
    >lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4354] (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02aa]

    Kernel driver in use: sky2
--

0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312
802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)   Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

```
  >iwconfig
```

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

> lsmod

```
nls_iso8859_1          12713  0 
dm_crypt               23051  0 
arc4                   12573  2 
bnep                   18258  2 
snd_hda_codec_idt      71153  1 
snd_hda_intel          44339  3 
parport_pc             28284  0 
rfcomm                 47864  0 
snd_hda_codec         141716  2 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
ppdev                  17113  0 
bluetooth             247024  10 bnep,rfcomm
lp                     17799  0 
b43                   392109  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
snd_hwdep              13668  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102477  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
joydev                 17613  0 
mac80211              630977  1 b43
snd_rawmidi            30417  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61930  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
coretemp               13596  0 
snd_timer              29989  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
uvcvideo               82214  0 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
cfg80211              525244  2 b43,mac80211
snd                    69533  15 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
gpio_ich               13526  0 
videobuf2_core         40785  1 uvcvideo
psmouse                97873  0 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
videodev              130053  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
snd_page_alloc         18798  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
dell_laptop            17425  0 
dell_wmi               12681  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13056  1 uvcvideo
lpc_ich                17144  0 
serio_raw              13215  0 
videobuf2_memops       13202  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
microcode              23017  0 
mac_hid                13253  0 
bcma                   41244  1 b43
sparse_keymap          13890  1 dell_wmi
dcdbas                 14449  1 dell_laptop
hid_generic            12540  0 
usbhid                 47346  0 
hid                   105549  2 hid_generic,usbhid
ums_realtek            18256  0 
usb_storage            61749  1 ums_realtek
i915                  620421  3 
wmi                    19256  1 dell_wmi
drm_kms_helper         49597  1 i915
ahci                   25879  1 
drm                   287564  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
libahci                31606  1 ahci
i2c_algo_bit           13564  1 i915
sky2                   62824  0 
video                  19652  1 i915
ssb                    57842  1 b43
```

**>rfkill list all**

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: no
```

**>sudo dpkg -s firmware-b43-lpphy-installer**

```
Package: firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: contrib/kernel
Installed-Size: 34
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
Architecture: all
Source: b43-fwcutter
Version: 1:015-9
Depends: b43-fwcutter (>= 1:015-9), bzip2, wget
Recommends: linux-image
Conflicts: firmware-b43-installer
Description: Installer package for firmware for the b43 driver (LP-PHY version)
 This package installs the firmware needed for usage of the b43 kernel
 driver.
 .
 Supported chipsets:
  - BCM4312 (with Low-Power aka LP-PHY)
Original-Maintainer: Fabrizio Regalli 
Homepage: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43
```

**>dmesg | grep -e wlan -e b43**

```
[  20.908424] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4312 WLAN found (core revision 15)
[  20.952236] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 6, Type 5 (LP), Revision 1
[  29.164261] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 478.104 (2008-07-01 00:50:23)
[  34.704994] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  34.705415] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

Comment: At the [b43 website](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43) the `wl` module is listed as an alternative to b43 for your device. Perhaps you can give a try to the Raring version of the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package (due to a bug in 12.04.3 the Precise version isn't working). See also http://askubuntu.com/a/337999/88802

Answer (score 2):

Is the wireless switch on or off?

```
rfkill list all
```

If it show hard blocked:yes, find and move the switch.

Have you installed the correct firmware package?

```
sudo dpkg -s firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

If it isn't installed, please get a temporary ethernet connection and install it:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and your wireless should be working.

If it is not working, look for error messages here:

```
dmesg | grep -e wlan -e b43
```

Comment: I posted the answers to hose queries in my original question. Thanks

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I've added the output of "dmesg | grep -e wlan -e b43" to my original post. I don't see any errors.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thanks @chili555

Answer (score 0):

I am almost embarrassed to answer because Iḿ not sure what is going on but I am traveling with a Dell Inspiron in Ecuador and I have had the exact same problem. What I have to do, **each time that I restart my computer is to go to edit connections and delete the connection where i am staying.** Then I have to reneter the password and I am back in business!