# Unable to get wireless to work 12.04 BCM4312 Dell Inspirion 1545

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, dell, broadcom

Long story short, I was playing with things that I shouldn't have and had to do a fresh install of 12.04.

After going through [How to Install Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers) with no luck. Then, became sort of tired of waiting for this to get updated [Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell Inspiron - Wireless stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340836/ubuntu-12-04-on-dell-inspiron-wireless-stopped-working/340870). Also went through [Broadcom 4312 wireless issues [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102282/broadcom-4312-wireless-issues/102388#102388). Went through some other ones but I couldn't find them again. I have nearly given up. This is definitely a duplicate in some form, but none of the other solutions have worked for me.

Right now I have uninstalled `bcmwl-kernel-source` and installed `b43-fwcutter` and `firmware-b43-lpphy-installer`.

Bellow is the info that seems to be popular

`$lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4354] (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: sky2

0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

`$ iwconfig`

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`$ lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_hda_codec_idt      64649  1 
joydev                 17329  0 
arc4                   12509  2 
snd_hda_intel          38819  3 
snd_hda_codec         118613  2 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                85934  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25157  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
b43                   364596  0 
i915                  550346  3 
snd_seq                51593  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
bnep                   17852  2 
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
drm_kms_helper         47749  1 i915
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
drm                   233935  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
uvcvideo               72250  0 
mac80211              541819  1 b43
coretemp               13324  0 
rfcomm                 38400  0 
dell_wmi               12601  0 
sparse_keymap          13658  1 dell_wmi
gpio_ich               13278  0 
bluetooth             211435  10 bnep,rfcomm
snd                    57014  15  snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_t    imer,snd_seq_device
videobuf2_core         39385  1 uvcvideo
videodev               96131  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
soundcore              12600  1 snd
lpc_ich                17048  0 
cfg80211              453853  2 b43,mac80211
videobuf2_vmalloc      12920  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13042  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_page_alloc         18398  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
parport_pc             27612  0 
wmi                    18744  1 dell_wmi
dell_laptop            17209  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13316  1 i915
ppdev                  12849  0 
psmouse                82769  0 
serio_raw              13031  0 
lp                     17455  0 
mac_hid                13077  0 
dcdbas                 14065  1 dell_laptop
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
bcma                   39810  1 b43
microcode              18433  0 
video                  19116  1 i915
ums_realtek            17928  0 
usb_storage            48053  1 ums_realtek
sky2                   53443  0 
ssb                    51554  1 b43
ahci                   25631  2 
libahci                26336  1 ahci
```

`$ rfkill list all`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`$ sudo dpkg -s firmware-b43-lpphy-installer`

```
Package: firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: contrib/kernel
Installed-Size: 34
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Source: b43-fwcutter
Version: 1:015-9
Depends: b43-fwcutter (>= 1:015-9), bzip2, wget
Recommends: linux-image
Conflicts: firmware-b43-installer
Description: Installer package for firmware for the b43 driver (LP-PHY version)
 This package installs the firmware needed for usage of the b43 kernel driver.
 .
 Supported chipsets:
  - BCM4312 (with Low-Power aka LP-PHY)
Original-Maintainer: Fabrizio Regalli <fabreg@fabreg.it>
Homepage: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43
```

`$ dmesg | grep -e wlan -e b43`

```
[    9.914782] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4312 WLAN found (core revision 15)
[    9.956245] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 6, Type 5 (LP), Revision 1
[   14.216271] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 478.104 (2008-07-01 00:50:23)
[   19.753302] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   19.755345] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

Just another quick note. As I have it now, I am able to Enable and disable wireless by clicking on the menu options on the top left. It seems like the wireless is working but it is not picking up any networks. Would post a screenshot but it doesn't take it if the menu is open :/. Confirmed that wireless card is functional through Windows boot. Also double checked router with multiple devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bump....anybody?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285463/bcm-4312-lp-phy-card-doesnt-detect-any-wireless-networks