# broadcom STA Driver failed to install

Tags: drivers, broadcom

here is another guy bothering you about Broadcom wireless drivers. I know there are a lot of answered questions dealing with this issue, but none of the solutions seemed to work for me.

I'm running ubuntu 12.04LTS and wireless card is: `Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 [14e4:4727]`.
I already installed the necessary headers, but when I try to activate the driver in "Additional Drivers", I get

> "Sorry, installation of this driver failed". Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: I would appreciate a step by step solution as my linux knowledge is mediocre

Comment: which kernel are you using - `uname -a` - if its kernel 3.8 then this Q will apply to you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/337974/broadcom-sta-driver-fails-to-install-missing-wl-on-ubuntu-12-04-3-lts-linux-3

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I received a new laptop and decided to install ubuntu on it. Everything worked flawlessly.